# how can I determine if a memory slot is filled in a C Vector?

Tags: c, vector

The following function allows inserting an element at a given slot in a C-Vector implementation:

```
void CVectorInsert(CVector *cv, const void *elemAddr, int atIndex)
{
    assert(0 <= atIndex && atIndex <= cv->capacity);

    if (cv->numElements >= cv->capacity) {
        CVectorGrow(cv);
    }

    memmove((char *)cv->vector + (atIndex + 1) * cv->elemSize, (char *)cv->vector + atIndex * cv->elemSize, cv->elemSize * (cv->numElements - atIndex));
    memcpy((char *)cv->vector + atIndex * cv->elemSize, elemAddr, cv->elemSize);
    (cv->numElements)++;
}
```

If the `atIndex` position has been filled, and I need to shift the elements to make room, however if the `atIndex` position has not been filled, I just need to `memcpy` the element;
A high elevel idea of how the CVector is defined:

```
struct CVectorImplementation {   
    int numElements;
    int capacity;
    int elemSize;
    void *vector;
    CVectorCleanupElemFn cleanupFn;
};
```

how can I determine if the `atIndex` slot has been filled or not?

Answer (score 0):

Why not keep track of the furthest into the vector an element has been placed? If it is beyond that furthest element, update the variable and do no shifting. If it is not, you must shift. I don't think keeping track of a per-element 'has been filled or not' state makes sense, as it gives the container weird semantics. (For example, if slots 5 and 6 are filled and I insert into 5, I move 5 to 6 and 6 to 7, but if 5 is not filled then I do nothing and if 6 is not filled then nothing goes into 7? It's just weird)

Comment: could you tell me more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Cdcontainers - data containers for C.The cdcontainers interface is similar to C ++ STL.

https://github.com/maksimandrianov/cdcontainers

```
#define CDC_USE_SHORT_NAMES  // for short names (functions and structs without prefix cdc_*)
#include <cdcontainers/vector.h>
#include <cdcontainers/casts.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    vector_t *v;
    size_t i;

    if (vector_ctor(&v, NULL) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    if (vector_push_back(v, CDC_INT_TO_PTR(7)) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    if (vector_push_back(v, CDC_INT_TO_PTR(8)) != CDC_STATUS_OK)
        /* error handling */;

    for (i = 0; i < vector_size(v); ++i)
        printf("%i ", CDC_PTR_TO_INT(vector_get(v, i)));

    printf("\n");

    vector_dtor(v);

    return 0;
}
```